How to style Mapbox heatmap
I have this GeoJSON (can be downloaded here). The data is distributed through a grid, thus the points are distributed regularly.

However, each point has a different "weight" via the prop count assigned to it. The vast majority has count 1. The max value of count is 90. I want to display a heatmap with Mapbox, but it looks everywhere the same.

I would expect some areas to be darker in color and others not. But like this, it all looks the same...
These are my heatmap settings (note: its React code, which is why - have been converted to CamelCase)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Create a heatmap layer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.5.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.5.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
         #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = '...';
            const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: 'map',
                center: [52, 13],
                zoom: 4
            });
         
            map.on('load', () => {
                map.addSource('movementData', {
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': 'the/data/I/provided/for/download'
                });
         
                map.addLayer(
                    {
                        'id': 'movement-heat',
                        'type': 'heatmap',
                        'source': 'movementData',
                        'maxzoom': 15,
                        'paint': {
                            "heatmap-color": [
                                "interpolate",
                                [
                                  "linear"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "heatmap-density"
                                ],
                                0,
                                "rgba(33,102,172,0)",
                                0.2,
                                "#005F80",
                                0.4,
                                "rgb(209,229,240)",
                                0.6,
                                "rgb(253,219,199)",
                                0.8,
                                "rgb(239,138,98)",
                                1,
                                "rgb(178,24,43)"
                              ],
                              "heatmap-intensity": [
                                "interpolate",
                                [
                                  "linear"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "zoom"
                                ],
                                2,
                                1,
                                15,
                                4
                              ],
                              "heatmap-opacity": 0.7,
                              "heatmap-radius": [
                                "interpolate",
                                [
                                  "linear"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "zoom"
                                ],
                                2,
                                36,
                                15,
                                1
                              ],
                              "heatmap-weight": [
                                "interpolate",
                                [
                                  "linear"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "get",
                                  "value"
                                ],
                                1,
                                0,
                                90,
                                1
                              ]
                        }
                    },
                );
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Why are there no "denser" and "no-denser" areas being colored?

Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

@TomazicM The relevant bit is here. The data as well as the styling I picked. Of course I could wrap that in a lot of code like done here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/heatmap-layer/, but the main part is the data which I provided and the styling. But if thats what you want :)

Problem is in your heatmap-weight specification:
"heatmap-weight": [
  "interpolate",
  [
    "linear"
  ],
  [
    "get",
    "value"
  ],
  1, 0,
  90, 1
]

Instead of using actual value count from GeoJSON properties you left placeholder value value.
You have to specify heatmap-weight like this:
"heatmap-weight": [
  "interpolate",
  [
    "linear"
  ],
  [
    "get",
    "count"
  ],
  1, 0,
  90, 1
]

This is how heat map looks like then:


Oh dear.... Thank you so much!
